# Tab key doesn't complete commands in Run dialog

Tags: windows-xp, keyboard-shortcuts, autocomplete, productivity, run-dialog

I like to use the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key to complete or skip commands and links in shells and browsers when I am typing, but when I hit the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key in the Run dialog, it causes focus to leave the text box, so I'm forced to leave the home keys to use the arrow keys.

Is there a way change this behavior?

**Edit**: I found [here](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/130764-windows-explorer-autocomplete-turn-off.html) a flag that enables autocomplete in the Run dialog. This doesn't solve the problem, but it helps when the command you want is the first option listed, because you just press <kbd>Enter</kbd> instead of moving to arrow key and selecting the command. In my case this solves about 90% of cases.

Answer (score 2):

This registry setting should do it... it's always been a pain to find for me as well.

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\AutoComplete]
"Always Use Tab"=dword:00000001
```